# Как регулировать высоту QTextBrowser исходя из текста?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Есть QTextBrowser, в него добавляется текст неопределенной длины. Нужно, чтобы высота QTextBrowser подстраивалась под количества текста. Пробовал считать количество строк и под них указывать setMinimumHeight, но возникают проблемы, когда текст с абзацами, тегами и т.д. - много исключений.

Также нашел под C++ пример, но на PyQt получаю по такому примеру нулевой размер

```
QSize size = ui->textEdit->document()->size().toSize();
ui->textEdit->setFixedHeight( size.height()  );
```

Это возвращает 0:

```
text.document().size().height()
```

При добавлении текста при инициализации данный прием не срабатывает:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Demo(QWidget):    
    def __init__(self):        
        super().__init__()

        self.textBrowser = QTextBrowser()
        self.textBrowser.setFixedHeight(100)
        self.textBrowser.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)   # +

        text = \
            """
Есть QTextBrowser, в него добавляется текст неопределенной длины. Нужно, чтобы высота QTextBrowser подстраивалась под количества текста. Пробовал считать количество строк и под них указывать setMinimumHeight, но возникают проблемы, когда текст с абзацами, тегами и т.д. - много исключений.

Также нашел под C++ пример, но на PyQt получаю по такому примеру нулевой размер            
            """
        self.textBrowser.append(text)
        size = self.textBrowser.document().size().toSize()            # +++
        print(f'size = {size}')
        self.textBrowser.setFixedHeight(size.height())                # +++

        self.button = QPushButton("Show")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.showDb)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.textBrowser)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def showDb(self):
        text = \
            """
Есть QTextBrowser, в него добавляется текст неопределенной длины. Нужно, чтобы высота QTextBrowser подстраивалась под количества текста. Пробовал считать количество строк и под них указывать setMinimumHeight, но возникают проблемы, когда текст с абзацами, тегами и т.д. - много исключений.

Также нашел под C++ пример, но на PyQt получаю по такому примеру нулевой размер            
            """
        self.textBrowser.append(text)

        size = self.textBrowser.document().size().toSize()            # +++
        print(f'size = {size}')
        self.textBrowser.setFixedHeight(size.height())                # +++


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w  = Demo()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: положи его в layout и оно будет само тянуться

Comment: Он в Layout. Без указания text.setMinimumHeight(height_text) появляется прокрутка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не меняет размер и можно указать setMinimumWidth:

```
self.textBrowser.setMinimumWidth(500)
self.textBrowser.setAttribute(103)
self.textBrowser.show()
self.textBrowser.setFixedHeight(self.textBrowser.document().size().height())
```

Answer (score 0):

Я проверил то что вы нашли и это работает:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Demo(QWidget):    
    def __init__(self):        
        super().__init__()

        self.textBrowser = QTextBrowser()
        self.textBrowser.setFixedHeight(100)
        self.textBrowser.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)   # +

        self.button = QPushButton("Show")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.showDb)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.textBrowser)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def showDb(self):
        text = \
            """
Есть QTextBrowser, в него добавляется текст неопределенной длины. Нужно, чтобы высота QTextBrowser подстраивалась под количества текста. Пробовал считать количество строк и под них указывать setMinimumHeight, но возникают проблемы, когда текст с абзацами, тегами и т.д. - много исключений.

Также нашел под C++ пример, но на PyQt получаю по такому примеру нулевой размер            
            """
        self.textBrowser.append(text)

        size = self.textBrowser.document().size().toSize()            # +++
        print(f'size = {size}')
        self.textBrowser.setFixedHeight(size.height())                # +++


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w  = Demo()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> При добавлении текста при инициализации данный прием не срабатывает ?

При инициализации надо делать так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Demo(QWidget):    
    def __init__(self):        
        super().__init__()

        self.textBrowser = QTextBrowser()
        self.textBrowser.setFixedHeight(100)
        self.textBrowser.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)   # +

        text = \
            """
Есть QTextBrowser, в него добавляется текст неопределенной длины. Нужно, чтобы высота QTextBrowser подстраивалась под количества текста. Пробовал считать количество строк и под них указывать setMinimumHeight, но возникают проблемы, когда текст с абзацами, тегами и т.д. - много исключений.

Также нашел под C++ пример, но на PyQt получаю по такому примеру нулевой размер            
            """
        self.textBrowser.append(text)

#        size = self.textBrowser.document().size().toSize()
#        size = self.textBrowser.document().size().toSize()
#        print(f'size = {size}')
#        self.textBrowser.setFixedHeight(size.height())
        QTimer.singleShot(10, self.textBrowserDocument)              # +++ <----

        self.button = QPushButton("Show")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.showDb)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.textBrowser)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def textBrowserDocument(self):                                    # +++ <----
        size = self.textBrowser.document().size().toSize()            # +++
        print(f'size = {size}')
        self.textBrowser.setFixedHeight(size.height())                # +++    

    def showDb(self):
        text = \
            """
Есть QTextBrowser, в него добавляется текст неопределенной длины. Нужно, чтобы высота QTextBrowser подстраивалась под количества текста. Пробовал считать количество строк и под них указывать setMinimumHeight, но возникают проблемы, когда текст с абзацами, тегами и т.д. - много исключений.

Также нашел под C++ пример, но на PyQt получаю по такому примеру нулевой размер            
            """
        self.textBrowser.append(text)

        size = self.textBrowser.document().size().toSize()            # +++
        print(f'size = {size}')
        self.textBrowser.setFixedHeight(size.height())                # +++


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w  = Demo()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня не работало, потому что я setText использовал, а не append. В таком случае почему-то не возвращает размер.

Но текст добавляю не по кнопке. И если добавление текста и задать высоту произвести в инициализации, то выставляется размер (8,21) изначально. С чем это связано? И как можно корректно при инициализации выставить корректный размер?

Comment: @WD_KMS я буду смотреть ваши вопросы только при наличии полного кода, который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Добавил в стартовый пост

Comment: @WD_KMS я добавил решение вашего дополнительного вопроса.

Comment: @WD_KMS вопрос решен ? или есть еще вопросы?

Comment: QTimer не подошёл. Остановился на решении:
        self.textBrowser.setAttribute(103)
        self.textBrowser.show()
        self.textBrowser.setFixedHeight(self.textBrowser.document().size().height())
С предварительной установкой setMinimumWidth для содержащего QTextBrowser виджета